# Node HTTP Server does not respond to first request within Electron

Tags: node.js, http, electron

I'm trying to start a local server in Electron to capture Google's OAuth callback like so:

```
this.server = http.createServer((request, response) => {
      const { query } = url.parse(request.url, true);
      if (query.code) {
        this.onCodeReceived(query.code);
        // do something nicer here eventually
        response.end();
      } else {
        response.end('Error');
        this.authStatus = 'error';
      }
    }).listen(this.LOCAL_SERVER_PORT);
```

The issue I'm having is that when I finish authenticating with Google the window just sits at "Waiting for 127.0.0.1..." and never actually finishes. I've found using console.log in the request handler that the handler is never actually called, so I'm stumped as to why the request isn't going through.

I've verified that the callback URL has the same port the server is listening to, and that the server actually begins listening. Weirdly if I open a new tab and go to the URI I get the expected Error response.

For reference the callback URI is set as `http://127.0.0.1:18363` and `this.LOCAL_SERVER_PORT = 18363`.

If anyone has any ideas I'd greatly appreciate it. Thank you!

Comment: Can you add the rest of the code?

Comment: `127.0.0.1` is `localhost`, you're telling Google's OAuth to call itself, you need to pass a public IP address to the API.